# Is this a bijection between $V_{\omega+1}$ and the 2-adic numbers?

Tags: set-theory, p-adic-number-theory

There exists the nice bijection by Ackermann from the set of hereditarily finite sets ($V_\omega$ in the von-Neumann hierarchy) to the natural numbers,
$$f:V_\omega\to\mathbb N, M \mapsto f(M) = \sum_{X\in M} 2^{f(X)} \tag 1$$
(note that the function above is the inverse of the function given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set)).

Now I thought about whether that would be extensible to infinite sets. The next step in the von-Neumann hierarchy is, of course, $V_{\omega+1}$. Now if one naively applies the above formula to sets in $V_{\omega+1}$, one notices that one still gets sums of powers of $2$ (because their elements are all hereditarily finite), but there may be infinitely many of them in the sum.

But there happens to be a theory where exactly such sums appear: The [2-adic numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) Therefore I conclude that the same formula, applied to elements of $V_{\omega+1}$ instead of $V_\omega$, gives a mapping to the $2$-adic numbers (of course the sum has to be interpreted as 2-adic sum instead of natural number sum in that case). It seems obvious that this mapping is surjective (as all possible  sums of powers of $2$ occur). However I wonder: Is it also injective (and thus bijective), just as in the case of $V_\omega$?

Comment: @aerdna91: Why is the [set-theory] tag more appropriate?

Comment: @AsafKaragila From the elementary-set-theory "about" page: "This tag is for elementary questions on set theory, focusing on material usually covered in undergraduate set theory texts". I've never seen an undergraduate course covering the Von Neumann hierarchy (even though I'm sure there exist some). Moreover, the specific topics mentioned in the same page make me think that this question fits the set-theory tag better, whose "about" page indeed mentions "transfinite hierarchies" explicitly. Of course you know math.SE much better than me and I might be wrong!

Comment: @aerdna91: It's a borderline question on the boundary of both tags. I'll leave it for someone else to decide whether or not to revert it to the original tag.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok. Even without looking at the "about" pages for a second, my impression (both based on memory and on the first 45 questions with such tag) is that most of the elementary-set-theory questions are about topics of the first semester. Then there are some which are about naive set theory. It rarely happens that the question requires ordinals or transfinite recursion.

Comment: @aerdna91: Not entirely correct, actually.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You know better for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the mapping is not surjective for the $p$-adic *numbers*, but on the $p$-adic *integers* (back then, I overlooked that $p$-adic numbers can have negative exponents, which obviously cannot occur for the Ackermann numbering.

That the map to the $p$-adic integers is indeed a bijection can be seen as follows:

Be $A_k = \{x\in V_\omega: \max\{f(y):y\in x\}<k\}$. That is, the set of all hereditary finite sets all of whose elements have an Ackermann number less than $k$. Be further $\phi_{kl}:A_l\to A_k$ defined as $f_{kl}(x) =  \{y\in x: .f(y)<k\}$. Then obviously the inverse limit of $A_k$ is $V_{\omega+1}$, with the projections $\pi_k:V_{\omega+1}\to A_k,x\mapsto\{y\in x:f(y)<k\}$.

On the other hand, it is not hard to check that $B_n:=\{f(x):x\in A_n\} = \{n\in\mathbb N:n<2^k\}$ and $\chi(n):=f(\phi_kl(f^{-1}(n)))\equiv n \pmod{2^k}$. That is, for each set $x$, the sequence $f(\pi_k(x))$ defines a sequence that in the inverse limit for $B_n$ gives, by definition, a $p$-adic integer.

Obviously different sets give different sequences, and therefore different $p$-adic integers. On the other hand, it is easily seen that every sequence of valid integers can be reached, since the finite sets ultimately correspond to the binary representation of the integers, and taking a number modulo $2^k$ just means taking the last $k$ binary digits.

Comment: Is there any reference in the literature that talks about this?